# Is it necessary to do security patches before upgrading Magento?

Tags: patches, security

I am new to Magento. I got a Magento project which I need to upgrade. To do so I read in some tutorials that there are security patches to be performed before upgrading Magento.

I am curious if those security patches can be done after the upgrade? Since the patches are often available for multiple Magento versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the description for the version you intend on upgrading to. It will tell you what patches are included. If you **upgrade to the very latest version** of Magento, you will have all the security patches included.

This is now standard policy since the "Shoplift Bug" issue for Magento to make sure all security patches get released along side a full install version.